# I want something where the number before the decimal have font size more than the numbers after decimal

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want something where the number before the decimal have font size more than the numbers after decimal. I have done this using jquery by assigning class. Is there any way for doing the same in angularjs ][1]

```
    .tdSplit {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .tdGreen {
       font-size:20px;
    }

    .tdRed {
       font-size:10px;
    }
</style>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tdSplit').each(function (index, obj) {
            var vPreAmount = obj.innerText.split(".")[0];
            var vPostAmount = obj.innerText.split(".")[1];
            obj.innerHTML = "<span class='tdGreen'>" + vPreAmount + ".</span><span class='tdRed'>" + vPostAmount + "</span>";
        });
    });
</script>

    <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td>Amount 1:</td>
                <td class="tdSplit">10234.56</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount 2:</td>
                <td class="tdSplit">5677.67</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: create a simple custom filter in angular and put each expression inside a different span class

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a custom filter:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('money', function($sce) {
  return function(data) {
      var strData = parseFloat(Math.round(data * 100) / 100).toFixed(2); 
      var vPreAmount = strData.split(".")[0];
      var vPostAmount = strData.split(".")[1];
      var innerHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml("<span class='tdGreen'>$" + vPreAmount + ".</span><span class='tdRed'>" + vPostAmount + "</span>");
      return innerHTML;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .tdGreen {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .tdRed {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
<div ng-app="app">
  <span ng-bind-html="35.66 | money"></span>
</div>
```